# Unable to check time elapsed with Calendar.current.dateComponents

Tags: swift, safari-app-extension

I want to check how many seconds passed since one timestamp to now. I have this:

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: userInfo?["timestamp"], to: Date()).second! > preferences["secsToWait"]
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Type 'Any' has no member 'second'

Changing the code to this:

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.second], from: userInfo?["timestamp"], to: Date()).second! > preferences["secsToWait"]
```

changes the error message to:

> Cannot invoke 'dateComponents' with an argument list of type '([Calendar.Component], from: Any?, to: Date)'

I do have this on top:

```
import Foundation;
```

This code is called inside `SafariExtensionHandler` (if it matters). Any idea of what's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `userInfo` is of type `[AnyHashable : Any]`.  This means that the result of `userInfo?["timestamp"]` is of type `Any?`.  Without seeing how you are storing that info I assume you are actually passing a `Date` object in, in which case you need to unwrap the timestamp before you can use it.  The safest way would be:

```
if let timestamp = userInfo?["timestamp"] as? Date {
  //Do whatever you were going to do with
  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: timestamp, to: Date()).second! > preferences["secsToWait"]
}
```

You could also just do:

```
//This will crash if the value is nil or if it's not actually a Date
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: userInfo!["timestamp"] as! Date, to: Date()).second! > preferences["secsToWait"]
```